# How does AppHarbor select what to unit-test?

Tags: unit-testing, appharbor, xunit

I have just created a small project with AppHarbor, composed of a single .csproj that uses xUnit. It's using NuGet to recover the xUnit framework. AppHarbor recognized it was a test project and executed the tests that were present.

I want to know how AppHarbor select which projects to unit test. Does it look at the referenced assemblies of the dll/exe (perhaps through reflection)? (for example if the dll/exe references xunit.dll then it's probably a test project). Does it look at the .csproj file looking for the references? Does it run all the assemblies through all the runners?

Answer (score 1):

Appharbor uses Galio http://www.gallio.org/  I'm pretty sure its going to run everything that is marked with [Fact]

Comment: There are at least five frameworks officially supported by AppHarbor. It's probably more complex than that.

Comment: I would guess it looks at the .csproj to determine which unit test framework you are using versus reflection.  But its just a guess.